# How to show multiseries stacked bar chart in Asp.net using Fusion chart version 2.0?

Tags: asp.net, fusioncharts

I want to show multiseries stacked bar chart considering Previous and Current year as series
using Fusion chart version 2.0. Can anyone help me in this?
Please reply with chart rendering .swf file name and if possible with code.

Thanks,
Yuoraj

Answer (score 0):

FusionCharts v2.0 is quite old whereas FusionCharts XT v3.3.1 is the most advanced version with most advanced API and it provides many features.

All you need to do is to add necessary files into your project, please follow these steps:

1) Include FusionCharts.js and StackedBar2D.swf in your project folder along with FusionCharts wrapper class (FusionCharts.dll)

2) Then, you would need to build the chart specific XML for for the chart (in your case it is StackedBar2D.swf) and pass this XML in the RenderChart() method.

You can download the sample from below link.(uses FusionCharts XT v3.3.1 Service Release 3 files )
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bt512y8d3lg1fxn/StackedBar2D_Demo.zip

For more information, please refer this link:
http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/guide-for-web-developers/csnet/CS_BasicExample.html